# XSD Hierarchical key structure

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, constraints, schema

I want to set a composite key on 'AxisConfiguration' for each MotionControl and reference them in 'PredefinedPositions'.
The Axis-Attribute has to be unique for each MotionControl.
The idea was to set a key on 'Id' of MotionControl and 'Axis' of AxisConfiguration.
But it does not work and I don't know how to realize it now.

```
<Root>
    <MotionControls>
        <MotionControl Id="1">
            <AxisConfigurations>
                <AxisConfiguration Axis="A0" MappedTo="X" Type="Linear" MaxVelocity="0" Offset="0"/>
                <AxisConfiguration Axis="A1" MappedTo="Y" Type="Linear" MaxVelocity="0" Offset="0"/>
            </AxisConfigurations>
        </MotionControl>
        <MotionControl Id="2">
            <AxisConfigurations>
                <AxisConfiguration Axis="A0" MappedTo="X" Type="Linear" MaxVelocity="0" Offset="0"/>
                <AxisConfiguration Axis="A1" MappedTo="Y" Type="Linear" MaxVelocity="0" Offset="0"/>
            </AxisConfigurations>
        </MotionControl>
    </MotionControls>
    <PredefinedPositions>
        <PredefinedPosition Name="PositionWorkingRoomHome" Order="Z,X,YA">
            <AxisPositions>
                <AxisPosition MotionControlId="1" Axis="A0" Value="1000"/>
                <AxisPosition MotionControlId="2" Axis="A0" Value="95000"/>
            </AxisPositions>
        </PredefinedPosition>
    </PredefinedPositions>
</Root>

 <xs:key name="PK_Axis">
  <xs:selector xpath=".//MotionControl"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@Id"/>
  <xs:field xpath="AxisConfigurations/AxisConfiguration/@Axis"/>
</xs:key>
<xs:keyref name="FK_Axis" refer="PK_Axis">
  <xs:selector xpath=".//AxisPosition"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@MotionControlId"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@Axis"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

Validation result:

> Field "./AxisConfigurations/AxisConfiguration/@Axis" of identity constraint "PK_Axis" matches more than one value within the scope of its selector; fields must match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us where the key/keyref constraints appear in your schema, and that's critical.

But having said that, I'm not sure this can be done. The rules for what happens when key and keyref appear on different elements are so complicated that I'm not sure I'm right, but I can't think of a way to do it.

It's easy enough with XSD 1.1 assertions, of course: in the declaration of `Root` you can assert

```
every $ap in .//AxisPosition satisfies 
  some $ac in .//AxisConfiguration satisfies 
    ($ap/@Axis = $ac/@Axis 
      and $ap/@MotionControlId = $ac/ancestor::MotionControl/@Id)
```

Could probably be made a tiny bit more efficient as:

```
    every $ap in .//AxisPosition satisfies 
      exists(MotionControls/MotionControl[@Id = $ap/MotionControl 
        and AxisConfigurations/AxisConfiguration/@Axis = $ap/@MotionControlId])
```

Comment: it appears on root, in real root = machine in my schema. The asseartion does not work "Assertion evaluation ('           every $ap in .//AxisPosition             satisfies some $ac in .//AxisConfiguration               satisfies ($ap/@Axis = $ac/@Axis and $ap/MotionControlId = $ac/ancestor::MotionControl/@ID)') for element 'Machine' on schema type '#AnonType_Machine' did not succeed. " after validation

Comment: Working now, @ID was written in uppercase, that was the problem